# ERROR in node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(678,29): error TS1005: ';' expected

Tags: angular6, pdfjs-dist

I have a project that is still using Angular 6.

I upgraded NodeJs to 14.18.1 and fixed the node-sass issue with version ^4.14.1.

When I execute "npm run start:local" (running local at port 8080), I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(678,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(679,30): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(679,36): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(679,42): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(680,33): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(680,39): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(680,45): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(681,40): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(681,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(681,52): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(682,40): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(682,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(682,52): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(683,22): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(683,34): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(683,40): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(683,46): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(684,26): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(684,38): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(684,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(684,50): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(685,32): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(685,38): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(685,44): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(686,28): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(686,34): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(687,21): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(687,27): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(688,27): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(688,37): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(688,43): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(688,49): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(689,12): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(689,18): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api.d.ts(690,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(9,25): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(9,26): error TS1003: Identifier expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(9,34): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(9,35): error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(14,23): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(14,45): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(14,56): error TS1005: ')' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(29,14): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(40,13): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(45,26): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(46,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(78,24): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(85,9): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(85,33): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(89,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(89,19): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(93,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(97,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(101,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(105,31): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(105,53): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/text_layer.d.ts(106,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I tried with typescript 2.8.4 but didn't help. How can I resolve this issue?

Here is my package.json file

```
"@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "@okta/okta-angular": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^5.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^2.3.5",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-http-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.2.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
```